# python-binance initializing client class gives error

Tags: python, cryptography, binance

I'm playing around with automated crypto trading and is trying to get the current price for the `stellar` or `XLM` cryptocurrency and being able to buy and sell it on `Binance`

I've decided to use and already installed `python-binance`. The installation was successful and all that, so then I opened up python on the console and ran the following lines

```py
from binance.client import Client
client = Client('heres my api key','heres my api secret')
```

and i got an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\junya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\binance\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from binance.depthcache import DepthCacheManager, OptionsDepthCacheManager, ThreadedDepthCacheManager  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\junya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\binance\depthcache.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .streams import BinanceSocketManager
  File "C:\Users\junya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\binance\streams.py", line 13, in <module>
    from websockets.exceptions import ConnectionClosedError
ImportError: cannot import name 'ConnectionClosedError' from 'websockets.exceptions' (C:\Users\junya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\websockets\exceptions.py)
```

How do I solve this error, or is this library not working anymore???
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a missing library to me, try to run this in a terminal then rerun the program :

```sh
pip install websocket-client
```

Comment: Nope, the package was already installed and running the command again (Requirement already satisfied: websocket-client) and trying the script still errors

Answer (score 0):

I have solved using the code below:

```
from binance.client import Client
from binance_conf import api_key,api_secret

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

info = client.get_account()
```

In the website: https://pypi.org/project/python-binance/

They use:

```
from binance import Client
```

However yo must use

```
from binance.client import Client
```

When I used .client it worked and the error disappeared.